# Are there robots with female characteristics in Isaac Asimov's stories?

Tags: isaac-asimov, robot-series

Are there any robots with female looks, personality, or at least name?

> Other than Hari Seldon's wife.

Comment: Hm... isn't this question unsuitable for this site, as it's asking for a list? (Sorry, but I didn't make up the rules.) Anyway, I remember a robot called M.A.(something), pronounced "Emma" from I, Robot. (Or from The Complete Robot, anyway. I really need to read those again.)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

["Feminine Intuition"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feminine_Intuition) features JN-5 (Jane).

You may also be interested in this [list of female robots (gynoids) from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fictional_gynoids).

That list includes

> Landaree, a Solarian gynoid from Asimov's *Robots and Empire*

Comment: From Wiki "Dors is probably one of the strongest and most developed female characters of the Foundation Series."  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dors_Venabili

Comment: @KentByerley, could be an answer, imho.

Comment: Late for the party, but just for the record: Bayta and Arkady Durell, Bliss/Gaia are also fine & well-developed fem characters in the series.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me that in one of the "Foundation" series novels, but possibly one that was out of sequence time-line wise, his wife (Dors Venabili?) was revealed to have been a robot.

Comment: If you have a secondary question, it should be asked as a [new question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), or posted as a comment if you're just seeking additional info for your answer